# Survival analysis where the total count of different types of events matter?

Tags: survival, hazard, proportional-hazards

I'm currently trying to conduct survival analysis where events are not just the binary variables of 1/0 (i.e., did the event happen or not). However, I'm not quite sure how to proceed in this case. My "events" are integers representing the count of non-mutually exclusive events. For instance, a value would be 3 if three kinds of events occurred (in the context of car insurance data, the three different events would be cracked axle, a smashed rear windshield, and a blown head gasket). It would be 2 if any two of these events happened, 1 if only one occurred, and 0 if none occurred

Currently, I'm interpreting any integer count greater than 0 as an event occurring (a conventional 1 or 0). However, I would like to capture the nuances between the different integer counts (3 versus 2 versus 1 versus 0). Should I apply a standard Cox Proportional Hazards model separately for each count level? That is to say, define an event as 1 when all three kinds of events occurred, define an event as 1 if more than two kinds events occurred, etc.

Thank you so much!